# How do I fix pink Hearthstone screen (android)?

Tags: technical-issues, hearthstone, android

Since the last update (yesterday, 16 March 2016) my Hearthstone screen is not as it used to be. I like pink, but not this much. How do I fix this?

[image: pinky screeny]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://eu.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/20054739/hearthstone-patch-notes-420-14-03-2016

Haven't tried it my self so far. But comments of this post say if you can with your device erase the apps temporarly data, it will fix the problem allready, otherwise reinstalling seems to fix it for everyone.

> MAJOR TIP: If you're on mobile the screen would be pink after the update, to fix that you need to go to settings > applications > hearthstone > clear data
>   (Note: you will need to sign in again)

Is an upvoted comment there by  --"DeathIsHere"

Comment: I had the pink screen. "Clear Data" fixed it. Note that you'll have to re-enter your account credentials.